# PermissionDenied return to home

Tags: django

For my blog on all the relevant views such as delete and update I have this

```
    if request.user.id != post.author_id:
    raise PermissionDenied()
```

This is working as expected however it just sends the user to a page that says 403 forbidden. I would rather just redirect the user to the homepage.

Would it be insecure or poor practice to do something like `return HttpResponseRedirect('/')` or is it fine as is and I am overthinking it

Comment: You can use return redirect('/')

Comment: I would suggest returning to a custom page saying you don't have permission to do such and the relevant links to get the permission. You can then redirect to that page by `return render(request, 'template.html', context=your _context)`